# Stock analysis with python SVM/R for prediction of future values. Issue when running code

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, analysis, stock

This is just a section of the code. It runs but it never completes or stops. It is just a continuous process. Could anyone see where I am going wrong?

I believe it may be to do with the data reshape and then the svr analysis on the reshaped data as I have tried manual troubleshooting by commenting out lines and seeing errors. everything seems to run until it reaches the 'lin_svr'.

The code uses the dataset and creates two numpy arrays: 'index_list' and 'adj_close_prices'. the index and the close prices are appended to these arrays respectively and then the code attempts to plot the index against the close price. This is the aim of the code.

Could you point out where the mistake in the code may be?

```
index_list = np.array([])
adj_close_prices = np.array([])

##get the index and adjusted close prices
df_days = df.loc[:, 'index']
df_adj_close = df.loc[:, 'Adj Close']

for day in df_days:
    index_list = np.append(index_list, float(day))

for adj_close_price in df_adj_close:
    adj_close_prices = np.append(adj_close_prices, float(adj_close_price))

index_list = index_list.reshape(-1, 1)

lin_svr = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1000.0)
lin_svr.fit(index_list, adj_close_prices)

poly_svr = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1000.0, degree=2)
poly_svr.fit(index_list, adj_close_prices)

rbf_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1000.0, gamma=0.15)
rbf_svr.fit(index_list, adj_close_prices)

##plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.scatter(index_list, adj_close_prices, color='red', label='Data')
plt.plot(index_list, rbf_svr.predict(index_list), color='green', label='RBF Model')
plt.plot(index_list, poly_svr.predict(index_list), color='orange', label='Polynomial Model')
plt.plot(index_list, lin_svr.predict(index_list), color='blue', label='Linear Model')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what the problem is, when you post just a part of the code, but not all the code in it's entirety.  Try my code sample below.

```
from utils import *
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mxnet import nd, autograd, gluon
from mxnet.gluon import nn, rnn
import mxnet as mx
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import math
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

context = mx.cpu(); model_ctx=mx.cpu()
mx.random.seed(1719)


def parser(x):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')


import yfinance as yf

# Get the data for the stock AAPL
start = '2019-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

data = yf.download('SBUX', start, end)


data = data.reset_index()
data

data.dtypes


# re-name field from 'Adj Close' to 'Adj_Close'
data = data.rename(columns={"Adj Close": "Adj_Close"})
data


data = data.loc[:,['Date','Adj_Close']]
       

# Plot all the close prices
# ((data.pct_change()+1).cumprod()).plot(figsize=(10, 7))


plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5), dpi=100)
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Adj_Close'], label='Starbucks Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('USD')
plt.title('Figure 2: Starbucks Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

That should get you pointed in the right direction.

You can find more, similar, code samples here.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/ARIMA%20Stock%20Price%20Prediction.ipynb